# React Universal App: Authenticated API Calls

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, isomorphic-javascript

I have been building a React Application, using redux for state management. After looking at tutorials online, I was able build a nice app which had login/logout functionality. But on refresh, I got a 404. I realized that it is client-side rendering. So, I added an express server which handles the routes, doing server side rendering.

The api I call for data fetch requires authentication. I call the api with the jwt token in componentDidMount. It works fine on the client side.

Here is my question:

But if the user refreshes the page, the server sends the html skeleton, followed by client making the call in componentDidMount. Can the data fetch be done on the server side? If yes, how would I get the token(from browsers' localStorage)?

Comment: It is unclear to me what is your question (there seems to be quite a few of them). Could you make your question more specific?

Comment: edited to limit the questions to 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get data from the browsers `localStorage`, because the server has no access to the browser. If you API needs an access token, then you must first render the page, get the token from `localStorage` and only then fetch the data form the API.

Comment: so in such apps which require authentication, there is no point rendering on server as I cannot have the data ?

Comment: You can still render components which are displayed regardless if user is authenticated (navbar, footer, etc.). SSR is useful for SEO as well.

Comment: Thanks Deividas. One last question - if I'm rendering on client, and just taking care of routing on server so that user does not get 404 on refresh. Will my app be called universal/isomorphic ?

Comment: According to this post (https://medium.com/@ghengeveld/isomorphism-vs-universal-javascript-4b47fb481beb#.l1l8li8jp) - yes.

Comment: Thanks a ton. It was really helpful